# Fail to SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(remoteUrl) even though I can open it from chrome

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
Logger.log("RemoteUrl: " + remoteUrl);
spreadsheetByUrl = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(remoteUrl);
```

Log:

> RemoteUrl: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...-wPq_LpwbcV9Y_WqS_jM/edit#gid=63610314`

I get this error, even though I can open this doc properly from the same identity that I run the code.

> Exception: Document ...-wPq_LpwbcV9Y_WqS_jM is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)
> _setupPerRemoteUrl @ Code.gs:118

Comment: Try removing `#gid=....` If that doesn't work add a [mcve]

Comment: Your spreadsheet id seem like incomplete, because normally the id start with digit?

Comment: Are you using two Google accounts? If yes, make sure the spreadsheet has been shared with the account you run the code with.

Comment: @KinSiang I removed some digits due to privacy

Comment: I see, it is fine to include `sheet id` such as #gid=xxxx, since I find no issue to run `openbyUrl` with entire URL also, maybe it is other root cause

Comment: Do you own the spreadsheet? What permissions do you have on it?